# Match record Name with Field ID in VF

Tags: apex, visualforce

I need to match the ID of an apex:outputfield, with the name of a record...

VF:

```
<apex:outputfield id="title" value="{!lab.content__c}"/>
<apex:outputfield id="lastname" value="{!lab.content__c}"/>
```

There is a custom object called Labels__c (lab), and the Name field is TEXT

APEX:

```
lable = [
    SELECT
        id,
        name,
        Country__c,
        content__c
    FROM label__c
    WHERE Country_c = :account[0].Country__c
    AND (VF-FIELD-ID = NAME) ];
```

I need to marry the record name (TEXT) to the field ID. So, If i had a record called title, it would assign to the field with the id "title"

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you want to provide dynamic value of id.Id is a string type and and you can only pass literal values in that.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<apex:outpufield>` will render as `<span>` in html. You cannot set the ID attribute dynamically to the VF page `<apex:outputfield>` tag even using jQuery `attr` function.

I would suggest you to change the `<apex:outputfield>` to `<span>` like this:

```
<span id="{!lab.Name}"> {!lab.content__c} <span/>
<span id="{!lab.Name}"> {!lab.content__c} <span/>
```

Again, here you need to consider the implications of duplicate ID assignment to the tags.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your input, but this is not the requirement. I dont need to set the ID attribute, I need to reference it in apex...